# Paypal Shopping Cart Sandbox Test Error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to recieve payments from my customers via paypal. And i want to create a system auto confirmation for success/fail payments.

Now i created a function which is below. But when I click to buy button. It redirects to me paypal sanbox page. But i recieve a message like that

> Your purchase couldn't be completed
>   There's a problem with the merchant's PayPal account. Please try again later.

What is the problem ? I'm newbie on Paypal.

```
public function paypal($products) { 
?>
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="authorization">
        <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="cihankusmez@facebook.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="TRY">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>paypal.php?do=success">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>paypal.php?do=fail"> 

        <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">  
        <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">  
        <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="9 Elm Street">  
        <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Apt 5">  
        <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Berwyn">  
        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">  
        <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19312">  
        <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="610">  
        <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="555">  
        <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1234">  
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="jdoe@zyzzyu.com">  

        <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">


        <?php foreach ($products['fields'] as $key => $product) { ?>
            <?php $i = $key + 1; ?> 
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo strip_tags($product['stock_code']." - ".$product['product']); ?>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $product['wholesale_price']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="discount_rate_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $product['discount_ratio'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $product['total_quantity']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $product['vat'] ?>">
        <?php } ?>

        <button id="paypal_button" type="submit" name="paypal_button" class="btn btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> <?php echo _('PAYPAL ile Satın Al'); ?>
        </button>
    </form>
<?php }
```

Comment: hey did you solve ur problem? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your account on PayPal and verify your sandbox account and apps are there.....mine are gone and hence the error.

Comment: i cannot reach paypal developer address now. May be problem caused by network connection ?